# Android: Running a periodic task with varying sleep interval

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, periodic-task

I am building an Android app which should fetch periodic updates from a server over the net, while in the background.

The response is a JSON object which contains both the data and the interval till the next update:

```json
{
   "data": ["blah1", "blah2", ...],
   "nextUpdateIntervalSeconds": 3600
}
```

I would like the app to fetch the next update after `nextUpdateIntervalSeconds`. In this example, the next update should be fetched after one hour. If the network call was unsuccessful, a default `nextUpdateIntervalSeconds` should be used.

How can I run periodic tasks with a varying sleep time in Android?

Comment: try to use alarm manager

Comment: ... but not with repeating alarm ... every time you execute update from server code set next alarm ... remeber that setting alarm will not survive boot ...

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getDataFromServer();
    }
}, nextUpdateIntervalSeconds); // in ms
```

**Edit**

Your variable `nextUpdateIntervalSeconds` must has a value in first interval. You should initialize it with your default value like;

```
public long nextUpdateIntervalSeconds = 3000;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use Android's AlarmManager to set one time alarm each time and register a PendingIntent for my BroadcastReceiver. After receiving the alarm broadcast to my BroadcastReceiver I would start a service to perform the ypdate and after the update I would set another one time alarm with the updated interval.

you can take a reference from here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks--mobile-5788

But they have set a recurring alarm that you need to change to one time alarm and call it again after updating the data.
Change the following

```
alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
```

to the following

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the interval value in sharedPreferences and overwrite that value every time i get new values from web servieces and use set intervel ever time from sharedPreferences